# How to cause my cat to bring in a dead thing

Tags: pets

Yesterday, my cat brought in a dead mouse. I tried to catch it from her and save it, but she just killed it. When she killed it I thought it was very cute when she held a dead thing in her jaw, so I wanted to take a picture, but she had disappeared out of the cat flap and it was night so I couldn't find her.

How can I ask my cat to bring me another dead thing so I can take a picture of her with the dead thing? Is there a specific time of year where my cat will bring me a dead thing? How can I increase the chances of her bringing me a dead thing?

Thanks.

Comment: rumor has it, cats do it to teach their humans how to fend for themselves, kind of as if their human is one of their kittens

Comment: Animal behavior and training isn't really within the spirit of this site, but we have a site about [Pets](http://pets.stackexchange.com) that should be a helpful resource. The question may have even have been asked already.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had no idea pets existed. I'll re-ask on there and see if they have any advice.

Comment: Go to pet store and buy a mouse.Pick a suitable closed room (guest bathroom perhaps). Go into room with cat and _caged_ mouse. Be sure to seal the bottom of the door with a towel or similar. Uncage the mouse. Cat will do her thing and you can video whole episode.

Answer (score 1):

Many cats are only occasional hunters, and even if they catch something (mouse, small bird, etc.), they'll only bring it to their human occasionally.  It's a reasonable approximation to say your cat brings you a mouse because they like you and can see you're unable to hunt for yourself -- and since cats aren't big on charity, they'll do so only when they're in the mood.

As noted in another answer, praising her when she does bring in a creature is probably the best thing you can do to make it more likely she'll do it again -- but how long it'll be until next time isn't something you can influence much.  Next time she hunts successfully and feels like sharing with that big, clumsy, nearly toothless cat who none the less shares with her, she'll bring you another mouse (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you should praise your cat. Then she might do it again. 
I'm not sure if supporting anyone or anything to kill stuff is a good thing, but that was not the question.

Comment: Of course I praised her, I cuddled her and gave her wet food in an effort to make her bring me some again, but nothing has worked.